# Secret Manager GCP

Tags: dockerfile, google-secret-manager

I am using **SecretManager** Service of GCP and is using client libraries to access secrets.
My prod and dev credentials are different.
If we want to use these client libraries, the service account file needs to exported as GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable. This is required as GCP checks whether the exported service account has the required permission to access Secrets.

As of now, I provide these service account file in code and export them in makefile and Dockerfile before the start of the server
Now, I want to access the service account file too from the SecretManager and that can't be done using client Libraries.
I went through the best practices of Secret Manager and there it is not recommended to provide secrets via filesystem or environment variables as it is vulnerable to attacks

The only option that I can think of is to access this service account file secret by using secretManager curl API in dockerfile but that would be complex as I also have to decode the utf-8 secret using bash.
curl "https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/secrets/secret-id/versions/version-id":access     --request "GET"     --header "authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"     --header "content-type: application/json"
Is there any other best practice recommended for handling this situation?

Comment: where is this code running?

Comment: For local dev, authenticate with `gcloud auth login`. On GCE/Cloud Run, use the machine identity. On GKE, use workload identity: https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/best-practices#access_control

Comment: @somethingsomething, the code will be running in a Cloud Run service